# Chrome Apps: Embed Website

Tags: embed, google-chrome-app

I'm new to developing Chrome Apps, and I want to embed a website inside a popup window. This is what I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <embed src="http://www.example.com" style="width:500px; height: 300px;">
  </body>
</html>
```

but it did not work.
(this HTML file did launch, I tested it with a Hello World program)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that is most certainly not what `<embed>` element is for.

What you're looking for is [`<webview>`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview).

Note: this requires you to add `"webview"` permission to your manifest.

Comment: You might want to actually read the docs. Especially the permissions part.